# Trying to get three seperate blog posts in each div

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, blogs

```
<section class="blog_posts clearfix">
    <h1>Latest Blog Posts</h1>
    <h2>We update our blog regularly with information that may be useful for your accident or injury case.</h2>


        <div class="blog_preview">

            <div class="blog_date">
                <h2 class="blog_month">Oct.</h2>
                <h1 class="blog_day">10</h1>
            </div>


            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <p>Posted by <span>Gary</span> on Oct 10, 2013 in <span>Blog | 6 Comments</span></p>

            <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
                <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post()?>
            <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            <?php endwhile;?>
            <?php endif;?>
            <a class="read_more" href="http://www.heslinlaw.org/bicycle-riding-in-philadelphia/">Read More</a>
        </div>

    <div class="blog_preview">
        <div class="blog_date">

            <h2 class="blog_month">Sept.</h2>
            <h1 class="blog_day">22</h1>

        </div>



        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p>Posted by <span>Gary</span> on Sep 22, 2013 in <span>Blog | 2 Comments</span></p>

        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post()?>
        <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php endif;?>
        <a class="read_more" href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>


    <div class="blog_preview">
        <div class="blog_date">
            <h2 class="blog_month">July.</h2>
            <h1 class="blog_day">13</h1>
        </div>


        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p>Posted by <span>Gary</span> on July 13, 2013 in <span>Blog | 4 Comments</span></p>

        <?php query_posts('p=78'); ?>
        <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post()?>
        <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
        <?php endwhile;?>
        <?php endif;?></p>
        <a class="read_more" href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
<a href="#" class="blue_button">See Our Blog</a>

</section>
</div>
```

It will display 'Home' for the permalinks, and the excerpt part doesn't display the correct text.

www.heslinlaw.org is the site im trying to convert to wordpress. I'm trying to get each div to display an excerpt from a blog post. it's on my front page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the 3 latest posts to appear try this:

```
<section class="blog_posts clearfix">
    <h1>Latest Blog Posts</h1>
    <h2>We update our blog regularly with information that may be useful for your accident or injury case.</h2>

<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 3 );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
?>

<div class="blog_preview">

            <div class="blog_date">
                <h2 class="blog_month">Oct.</h2>
                <h1 class="blog_day">10</h1>
            </div>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <p>Posted by <span>Gary</span> on Oct 10, 2013 in <span>Blog | 6 Comments</span></p>

            <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>
            <a class="read_more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>

        </div>
<?php
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<a href="#" class="blue_button">See Our Blog</a>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand how Wordpress generates post content.  Basically, functions like "the_permalink()" and "the_title()" return data from within The Loop (http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).  If you call those functions outside of the loop you'll get unexpected results.

```
    <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>

        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post()?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

            <p>...Wordpress functions to display author, date, whatever</p>

            <p><?php the_excerpt();?></p>

            <a class="read_more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a>

        <?php endwhile;?>

    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: it still said 'home' for the permalink, but you helped me understand the loop. thanks, appreciate it.